# Detect Freedom Apk Is Being Run Android

Tags: android, security, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, freedomjs

Good day. I am developing an in-app purchase variant and thus i have lot's of secure issues with Google Play Billing...seems Google does not want to take any notice of Freedom Apk at all and LuckyPatcher too...

•The Lucky Patcher hacking was disabled (I am able to track that my app was modified and do not let user proceed)

Meanwhile my app is being cracked with freedom (tested) and i just have no clue how to make the app secure against it. I have heard it is possible to know whether the freedom is being run or no with my application but no working example.

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Use the `getRunningAppProcesses()` of Activity Manager

Comment: damn i am dumb as hell....might be a solution you know,meanwhile the running process will give???the package name right?which may vary time to time as the freedom apk is not google play based one,so basically not a 100 working solution

Comment: You could also try determining if the device is rooted and if so search for the package on the device. But this is more intrusive.

Comment: hmmm i pretty much need to exactly know as for the package name it can be definatally changed or renamed from version to version

Comment: Pardon me, I misread your first comment - yes, there is no 100% surefire way to identify Freedom apk is being run on the device, because since it isn't a play-store app, any qualifying information (name, pkg name, etc) can change at any time. The only way would to be a blanket block of all rooted devices, but that will rule out even people not using Freedom apk. Theoretically you could scan the device's RAM for a signature resembling that of the Apk, but that is essentially barbaric and could be circumvented.